# Ocaml stays in system after apt remove and apt purge

Tags: ubuntu, ocaml

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 which i installed in a distant past. For some reason i have OCaml installed on it even though im pretty sure i never used it. Im trying to uninstall OCaml via

```
 sudo apt-get remove ocaml
 sudo apt-get purge ocaml
```

But all i get is

```
Package 'ocaml' is not installed, so not removed
```

But the OCaml icon still shows in the "Show Applications" option and if i type

```
ocaml
```

Im directed to an ocaml session. How can i completely remove it from my system, including the icon? If it helps: the response to

```
which ocaml
```

is

```
/usr/bin/ocaml
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check which package owns /usr/bin/ocaml with

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/ocaml
```

If no packages own `/usr/bin/ocaml`, it is safe to delete it by hand.

Comment: It worked. pdk -S /usr/bin/ocaml returned ocaml-interp. Removing it via pdkg --remove accused dependency errors because ocaml-nox depended on it but apt-get remove ocaml-interp solved the problem. Typing ocaml in my terminal no longer opens an ocaml session and the icon vanished. Thanks!